# GROUP BY in sqlite note working

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm using GROUP BY in my sql query.

Query is :

```
SELECT _id, message_type, message_type_id FROM msgs_list GROUP BY message_type_id
```

This query is not doing the functionality of GROUP BY. **It is functioning like:

```
SELECT _id, message_type, message_type_id FROM msgs_list
```

The same query is working perfectly on windows machine, when i download the Data Base from device to the Windows machine.

Observed result:

[image]

expected Result :

[image]

Can any body suggest the possible solution.

Thanks,
Sha.

Comment: Well, what are the *actual* results, what are the *expected* results, and what is the *input* data? (Chances are it's *not* a bug in SQLite which narrows the "expected" failures to either be 1. Invalid/unexpected query, perhaps one that is out of date, or 2. Unexpected data.)

Comment: @pst Please check the updated screen sots for more clarity.

Comment: How is the query being executed on Android? sqlite3 in remote shell or in the application code? I'm surprised there is no warning/error when executing that statement .. in any case, I'm curious as to why the behavior would *differ* based on the client.

Comment: I'm running query in app code. Just for validation of the query, i'm using LITA in windows machine.

Comment: Could you verify the results of sqlite3 in a remote shell? Just to make sure it truly is what the in-application code is returning .. I really would expect it to work consistently, even with dubiously referring to no-grouped/non-aggregate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Every one for the support.

The Problem is not with SQL Query. The problem is with `CursorTreeAdapter` which i'm using as Adapter for `ExpandibleListView`.

In the `getGroupCount()` method of adapter, I updated default count with `cursor.getCount()` . Now it's working as expected.

Once again, Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Regards,
Sha.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge GROUP BY clause can be used with either "aggregate_function" or Having clause.

**[The GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)**

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrong syntax, the syntax of the Group by is as follows:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
```

In your case you are  not using any aggregate_function.

Example:

```
SELECT Customer,OrderDate,SUM(OrderPrice) 
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer,OrderDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm will use the aggregate function and will let you know the result.

Comment: I tried the above provided aggregate.  `SELECT _id, message_type, message_type_id, COUNT(*) FROM msgs_list GROUP BY message_type_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 0`
 and     
`SELECT _id, message_type, message_type_id, COUNT(*) FROM msgs_list GROUP BY message_type_id`

Comment: What do you want to achieve?